# How to get the type of the key in mongoDB documents via python

Tags: python, mongodb

thanks for concerning my question :)
[here is the snapshot of Robomongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8rWB.png)

As you see, I can see the type of any key in any document in MongoDB. But How could I get the type in Python or MongoDB language?
Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PyMongo in your Python, the following code will print the type.

```
database_con = connection[database_name]
for collection_i in db.collection_names():
    collection_data = database_con[collection_i]
    for dict_j in collection_data.find():
        for key_k in dict_j.keys():        
            print type(dict_j[key_k])
```